# Downloaded file is not saved on local. Wep api + chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, header, mime-types, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm not able to enforce web browser (chrome) to save (anywhere) a file from web api controller method.

`[HttpGet("download/{id}")]
public FileContentResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
        try
        {
            var result = classARepository.Get(id);
            var vm = mapper.Map(result);
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
            var fileName = result.Name + ".json";
            Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=" +fileName;
            return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonResult), "application/octet-stream");
            //return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonResult), "application/json");
        }
        catch (Exception) {}
        return null;
}`

On client side response looks ok:

Headers:

...

Content-Disposition:inline; filename=P1.json

Content-Length:685

Content-Type:application/octet-stream

...

As a response (Response Tab) is a json file.
But web browser doesn't write a file in downloaded folder or -what is more desired option- doesn't allow to choose location for a saving file.

BTW. Returning a null if something goes wrong is not good idea, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Change content-disposition to:

```
Response.Headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment";
```

Also I set content-type as "application/json" and I changed consuming the API on a client side from jquery get method to window.open(url,...).

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is return **File(content_in_bytes, "application/octet-stream", filename_with_extension);**